Cosine of a multiple of arctangent
I would like to find an expression for the following:
$$\cos\left(\tfrac{1}{3} \arctan(B/A)\right)\\  
 \sin\left(\tfrac{1}{3} \arctan(B/A)\right)$$
This is a problem that comes up when trying to solve cubic equations using the cubic formula, which involves taking the cube root of a complex number. Those expressions appear when putting the solution into polar form. Consider the equation
$$2x^3-9x^2-17x+84=0$$
I know this equation has roots of $-3, \frac{7}{2},$ and $4$, but when trying to solve it using the cubic formula I end up with several complex numbers that look like
$$(A+Bi)^\frac{1}{3}$$
What I want to know is if there is a general expression for the above root. It seems like there should be since I know that the roots are much simpler, but I don't really know how to find it.

$\theta=arctan(b/a)$ suggests drawing a right triangle. $cos(\theta)$ is a ratio of the sides

@vallev given that $~\tan(\theta) = b/a,~$ the computation of $~\cos(\theta/3)~$ requires that you attack another cubic equation.  So, you (potentially) end up chasing your tail.

my tail?! oh no...

The method is basically the same as the one for computing "more standard" expressions like $\cos(\arctan x)$ for instance (cf. here).
Start by constructing a right triangle with catheti of lengths $A$ and $B$, hence an hypotenuse of length $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$. Considering the angle $\theta := \arctan(B/A)$, one knows that
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
   \cos\theta = \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \\
   \sin\theta = \frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}
\end{align}
\right.
$$
Now, we want to compute the quantities $\cos(\theta/3)$ and $\sin(\theta/3)$ in function of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$. Let's consider $\cos(\theta/3)$ for the moment.
The triple-angle formula, i.e. $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3\theta - 3\cos\theta$, permits to write a cubic equation for $x := \cos(\theta/3)$, namely $4x^3 - 3x - \cos\theta = 0$, whose real root is given by
$$
x = \frac{1}{2}\left((\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^{1/3} + (\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^{-1/3}\right),
$$
with $\sin\theta + \cos\theta = \frac{A+B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$, hence finally
$$
\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arctan\left(\frac{B}{A}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{A+B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)^{1/3} + \left(\frac{A+B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)^{-1/3}\right)
$$
I let you derive the expression for $\sin(\theta/3)$ thanks to the same procedure.
